# How does 'Interrupt on Change' work on a PIC 16f877A controller?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts, microchip, pic16f877a

I have a problem with my program. **I am using "interrupt on change" on a 16f877A microcontroller**. I use MikroC.

**What the program should do:**

The program should generate an interrupt when I press a button on port B4: B7 and set all the pins of port A to one while keeping the button pressed, if the button is released, port A turns off.

**What the program does:**
By pressing the button the pins of port A are activated, however they do not turn off when I release the button.

The code that is inside  **while loop works correctly**, the problem appears during the interruption.

This is my code:

```c
unsigned char count;
    
void interrupt () {
  if (INTCON.RBIF) {
    count++;
    PORTA = ~PORTA;
    if (portb);
    INTCON.RBIF=0;
  }
}

void main() {
  cont = 0;
  TRISB = 0xFF;
  PORTB = 0;
  PORTA = 0;
  TRISA = 0;
  TRISC = 0;
  PORTC = 0;
  INTCON = 0b10001000;
    
  while(1) {
    PORTC= ~PORTC;
    delay_ms(200);
  }
}
```

Thanks :D

****************New code Edited*************************
I have removed some of the wrong parts of the code. I rewrote it. Now pressing the button turns on PORT A; but I still don't understand why it doesn't turn off when I stop pressing the button.

````c
unsigned char count, x;
        
void interrupt () {
  if (INTCON.RBIF) {
    count++;
    PORTA =~ PORTA;
    x = PORTB;
    INTCON.RBIF = 0;
  }
}
     
void main() {
  count = 0;
  TRISB = 0xFF;
  TRISA = 0;
  PORTA = 0;
  TRISC = 0;
  PORTC = 0;
  INTCON = 0b10001000;
       
  while(1) {
    PORTC = ~ PORTC;
    delay_ms(200);
  }
}
```
````

Comment: What is your intention for the line `if(portb);`? It doesn't do anything, since it's a standalone statement due to the semicolon on the end. In fact it's likely that your compiler is optimizing it away entirely since it has no effect on the program. It's been over 10 years since I last used a PIC like yours, but as far as I remember you need to read `PORTB` before you clear the `RBIF` flag in order to reset the change-detection hardware which generates the interrupt. Also what is `portb` (in lowercase)? It's not the 'real' port register and I don't see you declaring a variable with that name.

Comment: Thanks for answering  :)

You were right. I have removed some of the wrong parts of the code. I rewrote it. Now pressing the button turns on PORT A; but I still don't understand why it doesn't turn off when I stop pressing the button. I have added the new code to the post above.

Comment: `Now pressing the button turns on PORT A; but I still don't understand why it doesn't turn off when I stop pressing the button.` Have you heard about **debouncing**?